# Array format adding extra layer using '=>'

Tags: php

I'm struggling to find a way to convert my object to the correct format.

I want to replace a function that we currently use on generating detailed array, as you can see below everything is static.

```
  private function departmentArray($content=[])
    {
            return [ static::$A_DEPT_ID => $content
                   , static::$O_DEPT_ID => $content
                   ];
    }
```

A sample result when that runs is this

```
{"3":{"complete":0,"incomplete":0},"5":{"complete":0,"incomplete":0}}
```

I converted the method

```
       private function departmentArray($content=[])
    {
        $depts = d::getAllMainDepartment();
  
        $dept_array = [];
        foreach ($depts as $dept) {
            $dept_array[] = array($dept->id => $content);
        }
        
        return $dept_array;
    }
```

The resulting format looks like this

```
[{"3":{"complete":0,"incomplete":0}},{"5":{"complete":0,"incomplete":0}}]
```

How can I maintain the same format on the first version of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't push into an associative array, you use the new key as an index.

```
$dept_array[$dept->id] = $content;
```